# Creating a hierarchy from simple strings (PHP)

Tags: php, design-patterns, hierarchy, classification

I have some strings in a DB: x, y, z, x1, x2, x12, x22, x23, y1, y2, y3, z1, z2 (don't take them literally).

From those strings, and having some rules of classification (strings x1, x2 and x3 "belong" to string x), I want to build some kind of OOP-ish that incorporates those rules of classification.

```
x
 x1
  x12
 x2
  x22
  x23
y
 y1
 y2
 y3
z
 z1
 z2
```

Basically, I want to make a menu from plain strings, knowing their relation.

My question is: what is the best method to store their relation to each other, so that I can pin-point their exact "location" within this hierarchy? Is there a design pattern that suits this problem? I though of entities having some property "depth" or "type".

Answer (score 1):

You could store menu items within a table having columns: `id, title, parent_id`

In PHP, you would then be able to have objects:

```
class MenuItem {
  $id = 0;
  $parent_id = 0;
  $title = ""; 
  $children = array();
}
```

You'll store children in the array using their ID as a key:

```
function add_child($menu_item) {
  $this->children[$menu_item->id] = $menu_item;
}
```

When loading from the DB, you'll build your menu by inserting menu items in it. Simply have an insert function within the MenuItem object:

```
function insert($menu_item) {
  if ($menu_item->parent_id==$this->id) {
    $this->add_child($menu_item);
    return true;
  }

  foreach ($children as $child) {
    if ($child->insert($menu_item))
      return true;
  }

  // return false if we could not insert it in any of our children
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
0:(x,null)
1:(x1,0)
2:(x12,1)
3:(x2,0)
4:(x22,3)
5:(x23,3)
[...]
```

'5:(x23,3)' means node 5 is a child of node 3 and contains 'x23'.
'0:(x,null)' means that node 0 is a top-node with no parent node.

this data-structure could be modeled by an numerical array that contains an array with two elements.

you have to parse that tree recursively.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by adding a `parent_id` column in the table. For each record, there will be a parent with value 0 or the primary id of some other record. Once you have this, you can write a recursive function to parse the tree.

Answer (score 0):

you can organize these values in a table like a nested set tree (http://www.edutech.ch/contribution/nstrees/index.php), and then is fairly easy to find all children, or a parent